# cannot implicitly convert type system.linq.iqueryable on inner join

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

im a rookie when it comes to asp.net but im trying to create a restfull api in asp.net. in the code below im trying to get data from Saldo and Vereniging.

the saldo table contains:

-saldoId
-VerenigingId
-LidId
-Bedrag

the Vereniging table contains:

VerenigingId
naam
locatie
facebookgroupId

what im trying to create is that the return statement returns all the Verenigingen from 1 LidId.

```
public class LibraryRepository : ILibraryRepository
{
    private LibraryContext _context;

    public LibraryRepository(LibraryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool Save()
    {
        return (_context.SaveChanges() >= 0);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Vereniging> GetVerenigingenperLid(int lidId)
    {

        return  _context.Vereniging    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
                    .Join(_context.Saldo, // the source table of the inner join
                    a => a.verenigingId,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
                    b => b.verenigingId,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
                    (a, b) => new { Vereniging = a, Saldo = b }) // selection
                    .Where(c => c.Saldo.lidId == lidId);

    }
```

}

i get the error:
Cannot implicitly conver type 'system.linq.IQueryable "<<"anonymous type: Library.API.Entities.Vereniging Vereniging, Library.API.Entities.Saldo Saldo>> to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable "<"Library.API.Entities.Vereniging>. An explicit conversion exists (are u missing a cast?).

I understand the problem im having. its because the return value consists of a piece Saldo and a Piece Vereniging.

but i dont know how to fix this or avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Your return type should match the type in projection. see illustration below.

[image: non-matching return type]
Add a `Select(...)` to the end of the query:

```
   // ...
   .Where(c => c.Saldo.lidId == lidId)
   // for example
   .Select(c => c.Vereniging);
```

Answer (score 0):

Return type of **GetVerenigingenperLid** is `IEnumerable<Vereniging>`, while you are returning `(a, b) => new { Vereniging = a, Saldo = b }` in the select.

To fix this, you need to declare new viewmodel class say **Viewmodel** which will contain **Vereniging** and **Saldo** as properties.

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public Vereniging {get;set;}
  public Saldo {get;set;}
}

public IEnumerable<ViewModel> GetVerenigingenperLid(int lidId)
{

    return  _context.Vereniging    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
                .Join(_context.Saldo, // the source table of the inner join
                a => a.verenigingId,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
                b => b.verenigingId,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
                (a, b) => new ViewModel { Vereniging = a, Saldo = b }) // selection
                .Where(c => c.Saldo.lidId == lidId);

}
```

Hope it helps